# Java and JDialogs

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I understand how to create an instance of a JDialog, but are they properly displayed the same way as a JFrame. Is all I have to do to make it function properly just set it to visible? Should anything else be done? Is this this correct and easiest way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you display your `JDialog`, you should probably [`pack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) it. Also, if you did not supply an owner for the `JDialog` when you created it, you should use [`setLocationRelativeTo(owner)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29) to make it pop up in the center of the owner.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When you call `pack()`, you're sizing all the components to (at least) their preferred size (in general). In addition, since you're using a dialog, you might also want it to be [modal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setModalExclusionType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalExclusionType)).

Comment: To display it just set visible to true?